# Mysql Dump using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I am trying to write a function that returns the whole dump of sql using this code:

```
$command = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=$hostname
    --user=$username ";
if ($password) 
        $command.= "--password=". $password ." "; 
$command.= $dbname;
var_dump(terminal($command));

function terminal($cmd)
{
    if (function_exists('system'))
    {
        ob_start();
        system($cmd, $retVal);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $function_used = "system";
    }
    else if(function_exists('passthru'))
    {
        ob_start();
        passthru($cmd, $retVal);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $function_used = "passthru";
    }
    else if(function_exists('exec'))
    {
        exec($cmd, $output, $retVal);
        $output = implode("n", $output);
        $function_used = "exec";
    }
    else if(function_exists('shell_exec'))
    {
        $output = shell_exec($cmd);
        $function_used = "shell_exec";
    }
    else 
    {
        $output = "Cannot execute shell commands";
        $retVal = 1;
    }
     return array('output' => $output, 'returnValue' => $retVal, 'functionUsed' => $function_used);
}
```

The database credentials are correct when i run that command in a normal command line it get the desired result.

The problem is that when i try it using these command, either function i use i get always an empty string as an output. On the other hand the return value is always 1 which results to true i think and means that the function is executed correctly otherwise i will get a false return value.

For example i use the 'system' as it is the fist i encounter. Is it corrent how i am getting the output?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have spaces in the path to the executable, you need to enclose it in double-quotes.

```
$command = "\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\bin\\mysqldump\" --add-drop-table --host=$hostname --user=$username ";
```